# Sending bulk notification emails without blocking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, bulk, subscription

For my client's custom-built CRM, I want users (technicians) to be notified of changes to marked cases via email.

This warrants a simple subscription mapping table between users and cases and automated emails to be sent every time a change is made to a case from within the logging method.

How do I send 10-100 emails to subscribed users without bogging down my logging method? My SMTP server is on a peer on my LAN, so sends should be quick, but ideally this should be handled by an external queuing process.

I can have a cron job send any outstanding emails every 10 minutes, but for this specific client cases are quite time-sensitive and instant notification (as instant as email can be) would be great.

How can I send bulk notification emails from within ASP.NET MVC without bogging down my logging method?

Answer (score 4):

Back in 2007 I was asked to look into a case where Web Server would suddenly freeze and start sending 503 errors and come back after a few minutes. Cutting a long story short it turned out at the end that it was sending email which was blocking the server (in addition to some bad code).

**Basically Microsoft's SMTP server is implemented as a single-thread service** - last I checked. This will mean that all your valuable ASP.NET threads serving requests will have to queue to a single thread monolithic application to send a not so urgent email. You need to decouple your web site from sending emails - that is what everyone does and there is a good reason for it.

Write your emails to a queue and have a process reading and sending emails.

Answer (score 2):

Sending emails from an ASP.NET application is not a good idea as it might monopolize valuable server resources. A better solution would be to setup a Windows Service to perform this task or even write a Console application which could be scheduled to run with Windows Scheduler. [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is a good solution you might take a look at allowing you to schedule jobs.

If you want those email sending to be triggered from within a particular controller action you could also have a separate WCF service which could be invoked asynchronously.

Comment: @FreshCode, yes MSMQ is also very good for this kind of tasks.